# time() gives the same value for two different dates

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the following codes here:

```
$start_date = date_parse('10-17-2017');
$end_date = date_parse('10-30-2017');

$start_time = time($start_date);
$now = time();
$end_time = time($end_date);

var_dump($start_time,$end_time, $now);
```

The output is this:

```
int(1508383949) int(1508383949) int(1508383949)
```

Why are they giving the same values?

I also tried using `strtotime`,

```
 $start_time = strtotime($start_date);
 $now = time();
 $end_time = strtotime($end_date);
```

And had this as the result:

```
bool(false) bool(false) int(1508384298)
```

Comment: In future, try solving your problem(s) by making a simple Google search, e.g. `php <library> <function>`. Searching for `php strtotime` would quickly get you to the official documentation where you can read about the arguments and return values of that function. If that does not help you, post your issue here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top of the mornin’ to you,

You get the same values, because

1. `time` doesn't accept any parameters
2. you use `date_parse` / `strtotime` **not** correctly

`strtotime` allows - next to many others - this 2 formats for dates: `m/d/y` and `d-m-y`. So you need to change your values from `10-17-2017` to `10/17/2017` or to `2017-10-17`.

My Solution:

```
<?php

    $start_time = strtotime('10/17/2017');
    $end_time   = strtotime('10/30/2017');
    $now        = time();

    var_dump($start_time, $end_time, $now);
```

Output:

```
int(1508212800) int(1509336000) int(1508385505)
```

You find more informations on PHP.net, just look for the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and the [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) functions. :3

Sincerely,
Sam

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.. I will surely take note of this. . :)

Answer (score 1):

The time function does not take any arguments. So the following wont work.

```
time($start_date);
```

with strtotime you need to have your date in either `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` format. Please check the hyphen and slash.

From the official docs of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.